# Electron.js - Suggestions for a Shared Local Database

Tags: database, nosql, relational-database, electron

I'm thinking of creating an electron app for my customer (a very small business), and all they have is a network drive (NAS) for me. So I'm trying to figure out a way for them to share my electron app's data locally (since running a server isn't really an option, let alone a database.)

Right now I'm thinking to save the data on the network drive so everyone can share it, but JSON format isn't really ideal for my data model. Is there any way I can have some sort of relational database system on their network (or within the app)?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using sqlite.  Sqlite supports multi-user (writes are blocked) and there is a node module sqlite.  On each user's computer the NAS has to be mapped to the same drive letter and permissions have to be fixed.

Not sure this will work but it sounds good!  It's just a old fashion peer network.

Comment: sounds like what I need :) Thanks!! Old fashion p2p network is easy and fun indeed.